# What effect does "quality" and "appeal" have on buildings?

Tags: dungeon-village

Price is fairly obvious, due to it's visual feedback, but what about the other building values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the in-game help:

- **Quality** increases the chance of the visiting adventurer to gain Satisfaction.  The higher the quality of the building, the better the chance of gaining satisfaction.
- **Appeal** means it gets visited more often.  Which, in turn, means you garner the stat bonuses from that building more often.

I'm not 100% sure how Appeal works with multiple buildings; it could be that adventurers spend more in time visiting all the buildings with high appeal.  Or, it could be just that they visit only the most highly appealing buildings before heading back out.  Either way, higher Appeal = more visited.